# I wrote this code a code with python 3 tkinter and it's giving me an error

Tags: python, tkinter

```
total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (feet_entry1, feet_entry2, feet_entry3))
def callback():
    global total
    l.configure(text= "The output MV is %s" % total, font='none 12 bold')
```

And it shows this error

```
total = sum(int(e.get()) for e in (feet_entry1, feet_entry2, feet_entry3))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: At least one of `feet_entry1`, `feet_entry2`, `feet_entry3` must be returning `''` when you call `.get()`. If you try in the interactive prompt `>>> int('')` you'll get the same error.

Comment: The title should enable other users with the same problem to find your question. Please edit your title to a more meaningful one

Answer (score 3):

At least one of `feet_entry1`, `feet_entry2`, `feet_entry3` must be returning `''` when you call `.get()`.

If you try in the interactive prompt you'll get the same error:

```
>>> int('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You could fix it by filtering out empty values:

```
sum(int(e.get()) for e in (feet_entry1, feet_entry2, feet_entry3)
    if e.get())
```

The `if e.get()` will convert the value to a boolean. Empty strings evaluate as `False` so it is ignored.

See the documentation for [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> vec = [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4]
>>> # filter the list to exclude negative numbers
>>> [x for x in vec if x >= 0]
[0, 2, 4]
```